# How to fix Connection reset by peer message from apache-spark?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I keep getting the the following exception very frequently and I wonder why this is happening? After researching I found I could do `.set("spark.submit.deployMode", "nio");` but that did not work either and I am using spark 2.0.0

```
WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from /172.31.3.245:46014
    java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:221)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:898)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
```

Comment: The connection has been reset by the peer. There's nothing you can do about it at this end, unless you're causing it, e.g. by sending data to a connection that has already been closed by the peer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was getting the same error even if I tried many things.My job used to get stuck throwing this error after running a very long time. I tried few work around which helped me to resolve. Although, I still get the same error by at least my job runs fine.

1. one reason could be the executors kills themselves thinking that they lost the connection from the master. I added the below configurations in spark-defaults.conf file.

   spark.network.timeout 10000000
   spark.executor.heartbeatInterval 10000000 
   basically,I have increased the network timeout and heartbeat interval
2. The particular step which used to get stuck, I just cached the dataframe that is used for processing (in the step which used to get stuck)

Note:- These are work arounds, I still see the same error in error logs but the my job does not get terminated.

Comment: if you still get the same error, please check the number of paritions and also check the executor memory and number of executors set in cofiguration. If not it should be default value.

Comment: The advise that ringed a bell for me. Thank you! Beside caching regularly, I also saved the crucial data frames to disk at regular intervals to resume later.

Comment: If you have a need for caching, I would recommend you write it in Parquet in HDFS. This way you will clear the lineage of transformations you have chained.

Comment: Hi @braj may you show what you did to cache the dataframe?

Comment: you could just do dataframe.cache()

Comment: and, once you are finished using it, dataframe.unpersist()

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I fixed this by reducing the amount of memory each worker was allowed to use. It seems having that being too close the physical memory limit caused the errors.