# "GC overhead limit exceeded" when running two actions in one Spark job; no problem when running separately

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, cloudera-cdh

I have the following Spark SQL code that checks the absence of certain dates in large tables (several billion rows):

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("yarn") \
    .appName("minimal_example") \
    .config('spark.submit.deployMode', 'client') \
    .getOrCreate()

SQL = '''
select distinct
  substr(entrydate, 1, 10) as datum,
  1 as in_table
from {table}
where entrydate >= '{datum}'
'''

print("RUN1")
df1 = spark.sql(SQL.format(datum='2017-01-01', table='table1'))
c1 = df1.count()
print("count1: ", c1)

print("RUN2")
df2 = spark.sql(SQL.format(datum='2017-01-01', table='table2'))
c2 = df2.count()
print("count2: ", c2)
```

Essentially, the function is simply getting the distinct dates from a table column.

Now the part I can't wrap my head around:

- Each call to `count()` on its own runs fine
- When I run each call as a separate `spark-submit` job, it works fine
- But if run them in succession like above, the second run produces the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o150.sql.
: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

My interpretation is that the garbage collection from the first run kicks in during the second run.

What I have tried:

1. Call spark.clearCache() at the beginning of each iteration
2. Call `spark._jvm.SparkSession.clearDefaultSession()`, `spark._jvm.SparkSession.clearActiveSession()` at the beginning of each iteration
3. Look at the Spark web UI and try to get sense out of the DAG and Storage tabs (the latter one does not display anything) to no avail
4. Change the order of the two `count`s. This results in a different error: `java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347392/how-to-fix-connection-reset-by-peer-message-from-apache-spark) for a similar error)

One last observation: The first call spins up >100 Spark/YARN executors, maybe Spark's dynamic allocation mechanism does not like that the second call is effectively a new job that has different requirements for executors?

Any help is much appreciated!

Environment: Spark 2.3 on Cloudera CDH 6.1 cluster.

#### Edit: Some more details

- The tables are persisted as Parquet files in HDFS, stats:

```
   +--------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+
   | table  |   # rows   |# cols |# files |   raw size   |
   +--------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+
   | table1 | 5660970439 |    46 |  49167 | 228876171398 |
   | table2 | 5656000217 |    52 |  80000 | 518996700170 |
   +--------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+
```

- Memory settings: Spark on YARN with dynamic allocation, min executor memory is 1GB, max is 72 GB, total cluster memory is ~300GB.
- The first `count()` spins up about 150 executors, fully utilizing the currently available memory resources

Comment: Could you try to persist after edates after join with dates? Also one more thing, how big can date_whitelist be?

Comment: Hi @AlexandrosBiratsis, I reduced my question to a minimal example, where no join is needed. The `whitelist` parameter in the previous version of my question was of size 1-3, so I don't think that had any effect.

Comment: What are the rough size of the tables you are acting on and what is the memory settings you are placing on driver and executor?

Comment: @afeldman I've added some meta info. Memory is requested dynamically by Spark and managed by YARN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After letting the problem sink in for a few days, I just tried increasing the *driver* memory:

`spark2-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 4G minimal_example.py`

Maybe the deciding factor was that my application is started in `client` mode. Apparently, the management of a large number of executors (and their removal) costs quite a lot of memory, even though the driver itself only receives the result of a simple `df.count()`.